# Use a variable in subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

Let's say I want to pass in the variable `NAME` into my `subprocess.call`. How could I do this?

Here is one of the unsuccessful solutions I have tried:

```
NAME="today"
subprocess.call("curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{\"text\":\"Daily production RDS backup created named : \" + NAME +}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0N#####/BL#########", shell=True)
```

Comment: Use f-string. For example: `name="firefox"`, `subprocess.call(f"{name}")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
NAME = 'today'
data = '{"text":"Daily production RDS backup created named: ' + NAME + '"}'
subprocess.call("curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '" + data + "' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0N#####/BL#########", shell=True)
```

... but is still somewhat unclear and could cause problems if `NAME` contains single or double quotes.

A better way to do this would be:

```
import json

NAME = 'today'
data = json.dumps({'text': 'Daily production RDS backup created named: ' + NAME})

subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-X', 'POST',
    '-H', 'Content-type: application/json',
    '--data', data,
    'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T0N#####/BL#########'
])
```

This second example makes it easier to separate the data and the command line, and is less confusing.